# SQL Server 2008 - Display row items in column without PIVOT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have three tables that store: TENANT, ROOMMATE and PERSON records.

The schema is as below:

```
Table: Tenant
HMYPERSON   SCODE   sFirstName sLastName
        1   t0011   fName       lName

Table: room
HMYPERSON   HMYTENANT   sRelationShip
    9458            1   Roommate
    1024            1   Other
    1025            1   Roommate
    1026            1   Guarantor

Table: Person
HMY     UCODE   ULASTNAME   sFIRSTNAME      iPersonType
9458    r0011   roommate1   roommate1Fname  93
1024    r0012   roommate2   roommate2Fname  93
1025    r0013   roommate3   roommate3Fname  93
1026    r0014   roommate4   roommate4Fname  90
```

TENANT table contains the TENANT records.
ROOM table contains occupants record.
And PERSON table contains all types of people in it (TENANT, ROOMMATE, VENDOR etc.)

HMYTENANT in ROOM table is a foreign key of TENANT table (HMYPERSON)

HMYPERSON in ROOM table is a foreign key of PERSON table (HMY)

IPERSONTYPE in PERSON table specifies what type of person record it is. (93 is roommate and 90 is a Guarantor)

I want to display all the tenant and their roommate names in a single row.
All the roommates should be displayed in the same row and in separate columns.
(One column for each roommate)

I have written a query that gives me the list of roommates, but in rows.

Here is what I have written:

```
Select t.scode, t.sLastname + ' ' + t.sFIRSTNAME TenantName, p.ULASTNAME + ' ' + p.sFIRSTNAME RoommateName
from tenant t
join room r on r.hmytenant = t.hmyperson
left join person p on p.hmy = r.hmyperson and (r.sRelationship <> 'Guarantor' or p.IPERSONTYPE<>90)
where t.hmyperson=1
```

This gives me output like below:

```
scode   Tenantname      RoommateName
t0011   lName fName     roommate1 roommate1Fname
t0011   lName fName     roommate2 roommate2Fname
t0011   lName fName     roommate3 roommate3Fname
```

But I want it like:

```
scode     Tenantname     Roommate1     Roommate2     Roommate3
```

Up to 5 roommates is sufficient.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: See: http://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
WITH A AS (SELECT HMYPERSON, HMYTENANT, SRELATIONSHIP, P.ULASTNAME, p.SFIRSTNAME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY HMYTENANT ORDER BY HMYPERSON) AS RN
            FROM ROOM R
            INNER JOIN PERSON P ON P.HMY = R.HMYPERSON  
                                AND (R.SRELATIONSHIP <> 'Guarantor' OR P.IPERSONTYPE<>90)           
            )
SELECT T.SCODE, T.SLASTNAME + ' ' + T.SFIRSTNAME TENANTNAME
        , A1.ULASTNAME + ' ' + A1.SFIRSTNAME ROOMMATENAME_1
        , A2.ULASTNAME + ' ' + A2.SFIRSTNAME ROOMMATENAME_2
        , A3.ULASTNAME + ' ' + A3.SFIRSTNAME ROOMMATENAME_3
        , A4.ULASTNAME + ' ' + A4.SFIRSTNAME ROOMMATENAME_4
        , A5.ULASTNAME + ' ' + A5.SFIRSTNAME ROOMMATENAME_5
FROM TENANT T
LEFT JOIN A A1 ON A1.HMYTENANT = T.HMYPERSON AND A1.RN=1
LEFT JOIN A A2 ON A2.HMYTENANT = T.HMYPERSON AND A2.RN=2
LEFT JOIN A A3 ON A3.HMYTENANT = T.HMYPERSON AND A3.RN=3
LEFT JOIN A A4 ON A4.HMYTENANT = T.HMYPERSON AND A4.RN=4
LEFT JOIN A A5 ON A5.HMYTENANT = T.HMYPERSON AND A5.RN=5
WHERE T.HMYPERSON=1
```

Output:

```
SCODE TENANTNAME  ROOMMATENAME_1           ROOMMATENAME_2           ROOMMATENAME_3           ROOMMATENAME_4           ROOMMATENAME_5
----- ----------- ------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------
t0011 lName fName roommate2 roommate2Fname roommate3 roommate3Fname roommate1 roommate1Fname NULL               NULL
```