# Pivot table with non-cardinal values

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a table that looks like

```
Test   Reader    Result
1      John      1.6
1      Jack      5.2
2      Ursula    2.5
3      Albert    3.0
2      Jack      5.1
```

And I know each test can have a maximum of 3 `Readers` so I want to create a table that looks like

```
Test    Reader_1 Result_1 Reader_2 Result_2 Reader_3 Result_3
1       John     1.6      Jack     5.2      (null)   (null)
2       Ursula   2.5      Jack     5.1      (null)   (null)
3       Albert   3.0      (null)   (null)   (null)   (null)
```

I looked around and it seems I need to use a PIVOT table. The only problem is that I found examples where an ordinal variable is used to create the columns. In this case case I have a predefined number of possible columns (3). Any ideas?

Comment: Can you look at what I just answered here (without using pivot) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43511952/sql-server-2008-display-row-items-in-column-without-pivot/43512523#43512523

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution that does not require multiple self-joins:

You can `PIVOT` on the result of the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function to get your desired output:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY test ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS rn
  FROM   your_table t
)
PIVOT ( MAX( Reader ) AS reader, MAX( result ) AS result FOR rn IN ( 1, 2, 3 ) );
```

**Output**:

```
TEST 1_READER 1_RESULT 2_READER 2_RESULT 3_READER 3_RESULT
---- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- --------
   1 John          1.6 Jack          5.2
   2 Ursula        2.5 Jack          5.1
   3 Albert        3.0
```

Or, just using aggregation functions:

```
SELECT test,
       MAX( CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN reader END ) AS reader_1,
       MAX( CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN result END ) AS result_1,
       MAX( CASE rn WHEN 2 THEN reader END ) AS reader_2,
       MAX( CASE rn WHEN 2 THEN result END ) AS result_2,
       MAX( CASE rn WHEN 3 THEN reader END ) AS reader_3,
       MAX( CASE rn WHEN 3 THEN result END ) AS result_3
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY test ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS rn
  FROM   your_table t
)
GROUP BY test;
```

Answer (score 0):

See my comment above.  I tried to convert for your table (T1):

```
 WITH TX AS (SELECT TEST, READER, RESULT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TEST ORDER BY READER) AS RN
            FROM T1
            )
SELECT T0.TEST
    , TT1.READER AS READER_1
    , TT1.RESULT AS RESULT_1
    , TT2.READER AS READER_2
    , TT2.RESULT AS RESULT_2
    , TT3.READER AS READER_3
    , TT3.RESULT AS RESULT_3
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TEST FROM T1) AS T0
LEFT JOIN TX TT1 ON T0.TEST = TT1.TEST AND TT1.RN=1
LEFT JOIN TX TT2 ON T0.TEST = TT2.TEST AND TT2.RN=2
LEFT JOIN TX TT3 ON T0.TEST = TT3.TEST AND TT3.RN=3;
```